# What kind of statements,keywords,arguments etc can span multiple lines,and what need "\" for this?

Tags: c, multiline

How to know what kind of "things" can span multiple lines in C code without needing a `\` character at the end of the line?And what kind of "things" need the `\`?How to know that?For example, in the following code, `if` and `printf()` work fine if I split them up in multiple lines.

```
 if
  (2<5)
   printf
      ("Hi");
```

But in the following code,`printf()` needs a `\` ,else shows error:

```
   printf("Hi \
        ");
```

Similarly,the following shows error without a `\`

```
   char name[]="Alexander the \
               great of Greece";
```

So please tell me how to know when to use the `\` while spanning multiple lines in C code, and when we can do without it?I mean, like `if` works both with and without the `\`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is about a concept called 'tokens'. A token is source-program text that the compiler does not break down into component elements. Literals (`42`, `"text"`), variable names, keywords are tokens.

Endline escaping is important for string constants only because it breaks apart a token. In your first example line breaks don't split tokens. All whitespace symbols between tokens are ignored.

The exception is macro definitions. A macro definition is ended with line break, so you need to escape it. But macros are not C code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break a string across lines, you can either use the \ as you have...

```
printf("Hello \
    World");
```

Or, alternatively, you can terminate the string with a " and then start a new string on the next line with no punctuation...

```
printf("Hello "
    "World");
```

To the best of my knowledge, the issue with lines applies in only two places... within a string and within a define..

```
#define MY_DEFINE(fp) \
   fprintf( fp, "Hello "\
       "World" );
```

In short, the \ character is telling the compiler this statement continues on the next line. However, C/C++ is not white-space dependent, so really the only place this would come up is on a statement that **is** expected to be on a single line... which would be a string or a define.

Comment: I have used it for function arguments as well,and also for `printf` and its arguments contained in `()` as in my question.

Comment: That's not my question, I want to know when we can avoid it (as in "if"), and when to use it.

Comment: In short, as I stated, the **only** time you need it is if you are breaking a string across lines without using end-quotes (tokens) or a define.

Answer (score 0):

C does not depend on line feeds.

You could use line feeds anywhere you like, as well as just not using them at all.

This implies seeing string literals as *one* token.

But, as in real life: Too much or to few, both does make life difficult. Happyness is matter of balance ... :-)

---

Please note that lines starting with a `#` are *not* C code, but pre-processor instructions.